# Simulator App Preview Video pixelated

Tags: ios, simctl, app-preview

I'm using the simulator to generate an App Store Preview video with the following command:

`xcrun simctl io booted recordVideo ~/Desktop/test.mp4`

It generates a video, but I get a lot of weird artifacts when I play the video. If I pop it into iMovie, it get's completely distorted and it just see green/blue frames.

Anyone having ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could solve the problem by opening the `mov` file in quicktime and by re-exporting it from there again. The strange artifacts in the video disappeared.

Comment: Thanks so much for this. Had the same problem with recordVideo and this fixed it!